# How to get spider name inside its own class?

Tags: scrapy

I have

```
class MyCrawler(Spider):
  name = "my_crawler"

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyCrawler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get the name I defined easily inside **init** please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `self.name`.

It is basic python.